# QGraphicsBlurEffect on parent widget only

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

I'm trying to show a widget on top of another and apply the `QGraphicsBlurEffect` only on the parent like this

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget* parent) :
QWidget(parent),
{
    QGraphicsBlurEffect* effect = new QGraphicsBlurEffect(this);
    parent->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
}
```

But the result is both widget are blur.

It seams like the effect is propagated to the childrens.

How can I apply the blur effect on the parent only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to **break** the parent-child relationship. There's no flags like `QGraphicsItem`'s `ItemIgnoresParentOpacity` for `QGraphicsEffects`.

Another solution would be to copy the ItemIgnoresParentOpacity mechanism and implement it for QGraphicsEffect, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.