# How to set the shadow around the window

Tags: qt, shadow, qmainwindow

I need to show shadow around my `mainWindow` and I cannot set `WA_TranslucentBackground` on it as I need to show a video.

How do I set a shadow for `QMainWindow` without making it transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to :

1. Create top level `QWidget`
2. Make it translucent and frameless

   > ```
   > setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);    
   > setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
   > ```
3. Insert your MainWindow into created widget. Left some margins for shadow (about 5-15 px)
4. Add [`QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html) to `MainWindow`:

   > ```
   > QGraphicsDropShadowEffect *wndShadow = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
   > wndShadow->setBlurRadius(9.0);
   > wndShadow->setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 160));
   > wndShadow->setOffset(4.0);
   > mainWindow->setGraphicsEffect(wndShadow);
   > ```

Result:

[image: A widget with drop shadow]

Comment: Isn´t the GraphicsEffect applied to all Childs as well? This would mean that every UI element inside the QMainWindow would have a shadow! Maybe you can just set the wrapping widgets background to the shadow color and don´t use graphicEffects at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19309151/2927205

Comment: @Mailerdaimon look at picture i attach. `QPushButton` has no shadow effect

Comment: How have you created the button? If you don't set the parent (new QPushButton(this);) is it destroyed correctly? I would not recommend creating widgets without parents if you can avoid it. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

Comment: BTW I like the approach, just want to be sure you are not introducing memory leaks with this which can easily happen if you don't use the ObjectTree mechanism.

Comment: I add `QPushButton` with Qt Designer on `MainWindow` so buttons have `MainWindow` class as parent. Then i add `MainWindow` as child of new `QWidget`, so when this `QWidget` will be destroyed `MainWindow` with buttons will be destroyed as child.

Comment: Strange... [QWidgets documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setGraphicsEffect) clearly states that 'setGraphicsEffect' applies to all Children of that widget... and this is the way it always worked for me.

Comment: Ah, i did. Yes, it's true, it's applied to all children, but i done some hack or workaround like: add to my `QWidget` method `addChild(QWidget*)`, where i just add it to main layout of this widget. So `MainWindow` will be pseudo-child of widget, but will be destroyed correctly.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i thanks, but is there any way to got this shadow effect without setting Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground?

Comment: @haris don't realy know,but it's the most popular solution and works fine.

Comment: @t3ft3l--i yes it do works, but I was still confused, for my video could not play on this transparent window. thanks your patience!

Comment: @haris do you try it? Some strange, nested items must be worked without changes. Which class you used for plaing videos?

Comment: @t3ft3l--i QLabel , play video by webrtc which need a parameter of winId()

Comment: @haris I just try, `pushButton->testAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` - return false. `QLabel` has the same behavior.Child widgets hasn't Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground flag